# Merge with kiln (mercurial )

Tags: mercurial, kiln

What are the best way to merge in kiln with another repository.

we have 3 repositories

- 1.7.5
- 1.7.6
- main-dev

So I fix a bug in an older version (1.7.5). That fix I would like to merge with version 1.7.6,  repository and in our main-dev repository..

How would I do this with mercurial (kiln)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kiln doesn't provide functionality that allows you to do a merge via Kiln's web UI. So you need to do an ordinary Mercurial merge locally and then push merged changsets to Kiln. There is a plenty of posts how to merge changesets in Mercurial, including some good ones on Kiln Stackexchange:

- [Kiln Branch and Merge How-To](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/372/kiln-branch-and-merge-how-to)
- [HgInit - Merging](http://hginit.com/04.html)
- [Mercurial Wiki - Merge](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Merge)
- [Mercurial best practice on dev + stable branch merge](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/861/mercurial-best-practice-on-dev-stable-branch-merge)

Comment: Kiln Stack Exchange is no more